# How to use sphinx 4 to read a wav file and generate a text out of the words said in the wav file

Tags: cmusphinx

I have already seen the microphone speech recognition but cant really find a way to use wav files instead of the microphone

Answer (score 2):

Transcriber demo is included in latest Sphinx4 sources:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java

You can download latest sphinx4 from github

http://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4

Comment: is it possible to use Pocketsphinx to transcribe an audio file into a text file? I saw a post:

pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -hmm en-us -lm en-us.lm.dmp 2> pocketsphinx.log

But the output file Pocketsphinx.log does NOT contain the transcription of file.wav. Could you help on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul.jl, right the output is printed on stdout, you need to add > pocketsphinx.out to save it to a file.